# How to check xmlhttpRequest in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

How to check `XMLHttpRequest` While I'm getting status as 200 why it's not checking my `xhr`

```
angular.module("productManagement").controller('Employee', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  $scope.GetdataBySubmit = function () {
    var GetData = EmployeeService.GetEmployeeData();
    debugger;
    GetData.then(function(d) {
      if (xhr.status == "200") {
        $scope.Employee = d.data;
        $('#TadleData').show();
      } else {
        console.log("")
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Here I'm Updating My `GetEmployeeData` Code

```
angular.module("productManagement").service("EmployeeService", function 
($http) {

  this.GetEmployeeData = function () {
    var x=$http({
        url: "http://localhost:9632/Api/Employee",
        method:"Get",
        data:JSON.stringify()
    })
    return x;
  }
})
```

Comment: Show the code of `GetEmployeeData` function, Check the `d` which I think is response. So just `d.status` should work

Comment: Your `xhr` is never being used...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to define and use `xhr` variable

As you are using `$http` and returning `Promise`, Use the `success` callback handler `response` object.

```
GetData.then(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 200) {
        $scope.Employee = response.data;
        $('#TadleData').show();
    }
}, function (response) {
    console.log("Do something on error")
})
```